# Question involving the definition of the derivative

Tags: calculus, definition

We know the the derivative of a function at $x_0$, $f’(x_0)$, can be defined as $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x_0-x}$.

Can $f’(-x_0)$ be defined as $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(-x)-f(-x_0)}{x-x_0}$, or does this contradict the definition of the derivative in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(-x_0)=\lim_{y\to-x_0}\frac{f(y)-f(-x_0)}{y-(-x_0)}=\lim_{-y=t\to x_0}\frac{f(-t)-f(-x_0)}{\color{red}{x_0-t}}$$

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that the denominator of your expression is incorrect, it should be $x_0-x$ as I have derived above.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you.